# Is there a Swift type for a string-based enum?

Tags: swift, generics, enums

I have a function that takes a `String` tag argument:

```
func findFooByTag(_ tag: String) -> Foo
```

Now I would like to make the code shorter and safer by introducing an enum for the valid tag values:

```
enum Tags: String {
    case one
    case two
    case three
}
```

But I still have to call the function with a `String`:

```
let foo = findFooByTag(Tags.one.rawValue)
```

Is there a way to say “`findFooByTag` takes any string-based enum”? I have found this:

```
func findFooByTag<T>(_ tag: T) -> Foo where T: RawRepresentable, T.RawValue == String
```

But that’s quite a mouthful. Is it at least possible to sweep that under the rug with a type alias somehow?

Answer (score 1):

What you have found looks awesome, but still I would suggest something like the following:

```
protocol Taggable {
    var raw: String { get }
}

extension String: Taggable {
    var raw: String { return self }
}

enum Tag: String, Taggable {
    var raw: String {
        return self.rawValue
    }

    case one = "aa"
    case two = "bb"
    case three = "cc"
}

func findByTag(_ tag: Taggable) {
    if tag.raw == "aa" { ... }
    // do something...
}

findByTag(Tag.one) // works
findByTag("abc")   // also works
```

Comment: How would you work with `tag` inside `findByTag`? All you know about it is that it’s an empty protocol.

Comment: @zoul I've filled some more contents.

Answer (score 1):

As there is nothing in common between `enum`'s having a `String` `RawValue`, there is no common type for these or no protocol to which all would conform.

However, Swift 4 introduces type constraints on associated types using where clauses as described in [SE-0142](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0142-associated-types-constraints.md). Using this new capability, you can define a protocol with an associated type the type constraints describing an `enum` with a `String` `rawValue`, then you only need to make your `Tags enum` conform to this protocol and you won't need the type constraint in your function definition anymore.

```
class Foo {}

protocol StringEnum {
    associatedtype EnumType: RawRepresentable = Self where EnumType.RawValue == String
    static func findFooByTag<EnumType>(_ tag: EnumType) -> Foo
}

extension StringEnum where EnumType == Self {
    static func findFooByTag<EnumType>(_ tag: EnumType) -> Foo {
        return Foo()
    }
}

enum Tags: String, StringEnum {
    case one
    case two
    case three
}

let foo = Tags.findFooByTag(Tags.one)
```

This is implementation of course could be improved, but this is just an example showing how you can use a `where` clause to implement the type constraint using a `protocol` and its `associatedType`.

Due to the default implementation fo the `findFooByTag` func in the protocol extension, you don't need to implement the function for all of your custom enum types having a `String` `rawValue`, you only need to declare them as conforming to the `StringEnum` protocol.

If you don't have Xcode9 installed, you can play around with this code in the IBM Swift Sandbox using [this](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59ad6396ee9e0f7656d4b853) link.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you can use any kind of wrapper object. For example:

```
enum TypeNotSpecifiedTag {
    case one
}

enum StringTag: String {
    case one
}

enum IntTag: Int {
    case one = 1
}

enum Wrapper<T>: RawRepresentable {
    typealias RawValue = T

    case value(T)

    init?(rawValue: RawValue) {
        self = .value(rawValue)
    }

    var rawValue: RawValue {
        switch self {
        case let .value(item):
            return item
        }
    }
}

print(Wrapper.value(TypeNotSpecifiedTag.one).rawValue) // "one"
print(Wrapper.value(StringTag.one.rawValue).rawValue) // "one"
print(Wrapper.value(IntTag.one.rawValue).rawValue) // 1
```

Notice, that according to [documentation about `RawValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rawrepresentable/1540809-rawvalue), you doesn't always need to specify `RawValue`, that's why first example also compile.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try do that with CustomStringConvertible?

```
enum Tags: String, CustomStringConvertible {
  case one
  case two
  case three

  var description: String {
    return self.rawValue
  }
}

func findFooByTag<T>(_ tag: T) -> Foo where T: CustomStringConvertible
```

looks more better

or just

```
func findFooByTag<T>(_ tag: CustomStringConvertible) -> Foo
```

Comment: `CustomStringConvertible` has nothing to do with what OP is trying to achieve. Any class can conform to `CustomStringCollectible`, the only requirement for conformance is to have a property named `description` of type `String`... Your function can be called with class types as well or with enum types having an `Int` `rawValue` or no `rawValue` at all, as long as they conform to `CustomStringConvertible`.